# Hyperbolic PDE with spiky behaviour

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following systems of hyperbolic PDEs

```
eqs = {D[
      P[τ, x], {τ, 
       2}] - (Exp[-2 τ] D[P[τ, x], {x, 2}] + 
       Exp[2 P[τ, x]] (D[Q[τ, x], τ]^2 - 
          Exp[-2 τ] D[Q[τ, x], x]^2)) == 0,
   D[Q[τ, x], {τ, 
       2}] - (Exp[-2 τ] D[Q[τ, x], {x, 2}] - 
       2 (D[P[τ, x], τ] D[Q[τ, x], τ] - 
          Exp[-2 τ] D[Q[τ, x], x] D[P[τ, x], x])) == 0};
```

Subject to the following boundary conditions

```
bcs = {
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, x] == 10 Cos[x], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Q\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, x] == 0, P[0, x] == 0, 
   Q[0, x] == Cos[x], P[τ, 0] == P[τ, 2 π], 
   Q[τ, 0] == Q[τ, 2 π]};
```

So far, I have tried something like

```
eqtot = Join[eqs, bcs];
sol = NDSolveValue[
    eqtot, {P[τ, x], Q[τ, x]}, {τ, 0, 6 π}, {x, 0, 
     2 π}, MaxStepSize -> 1/200]; // Timing
```

However, I am finding poor convergence as a change the MaxStepSize. So, I am searching for ways to improve the code above, and if possible, to find ways to evolve the system to larger times (say $48\pi$ or longer).

Comment: Look for `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`

Comment: I am not quite sure what the suggestion is here. I tried using ``PeriodicBoundaryCondition`` and I got worse results.

Comment: As far as I expirienced the constraint `P[\[Tau], 0] == P[\[Tau], 2 \[Pi]]` isn't sufficient, one has to use two periodic boundary conditions instead: `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[P[\[Tau], x], x == 0,  TranslationTransform[{ 2 Pi}]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[P[\[Tau], x], x == 2 Pi , TranslationTransform[{ -2 Pi}]] `

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I implement what you suggest, the code develops a singularity in finite time $\tau$. I cannot see any improvement.

Comment: What a pity! Were do the `eqs` come from? Especially part `Exp[2 P[\[Tau], x]]`?

Comment: These come from General Relativity - the study of Gowdy spacetimes with $\mathbb{T}^3$ topology (the unpolarised case).

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved using `"MethodOfLines"` with options `"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"`. First we rescale equations using substitutions $\tau \rightarrow 2 \pi L t$, and $x\rightarrow 2\pi L x$, then system end boundary conditions take a form

```
L = 24;
eqs = {D[
      P[t, x], {t, 2}] - (Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[P[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
       Exp[2 P[t, x]] (D[Q[t, x], t]^2 - 
          Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[Q[t, x], x]^2)) == 0, 
   D[Q[t, x], {t, 2}] - (Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[Q[t, x], {x, 2}] - 
       2 (D[P[t, x], t] D[Q[t, x], t] - 
          Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[Q[t, x], x] D[P[t, x], x])) == 0};
 bcs = {
  Derivative[1, 0][P][0, x]/(2 Pi L) == A Cos[2 Pi L x], 
  Derivative[1, 0][Q][0, x] == 0, P[0, x] == 0, 
     Q[0, x] == Cos[2 Pi L x], P[t, 0] == P[t, 1/L], 
     Q[t, 0] == Q[t, 1/L]};
eqtot = Join[eqs, bcs];
```

Numerical solution

```
sol = NDSolveValue[eqtot/.A->5/Pi, {P, Q}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1/L}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> Round[340 Pi], "MinPoints" -> Round[40 Pi], 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot3D[
  sol[[i]][t/(2 Pi L), x/(2 Pi L)], {t, 0, 48 Pi}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, AxesLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "x"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {i, 2}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Then we can play with parameter `A` to get stably result. For instance at `A=8/Pi` we have in 0.15 s this nice picture
[image: Figure 2]

**Update 1.** This is relatively stably result for `A=10`

```
eqs = {D[
      P[t, x], {t, 2}] - (Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[P[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
       Exp[2 P[t, x]] (D[Q[t, x], t]^2 - 
          Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[Q[t, x], x]^2)) == 0, 
   D[Q[t, x], {t, 2}] - (Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[Q[t, x], {x, 2}] - 
       2 (D[P[t, x], t] D[Q[t, x], t] - 
          Exp[-4 Pi L t] D[Q[t, x], x] D[P[t, x], x])) == 0};
L = 24; bcs = {
  Derivative[1, 0][P][0, x]/(2 Pi L) == A Cos[2 Pi L x], 
  Derivative[1, 0][Q][0, x] == 0, P[0, x] == 0, 
     Q[0, x] == Cos[2 Pi L x], P[t, 0] == P[t, 1/L], 
     Q[t, 0] == Q[t, 1/L]};
eqtot = Join[eqs, bcs];
sol = NDSolveValue[eqtot /. A -> 10, {P, Q}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1/L}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MaxPoints" -> Round[120 Pi], "MinPoints" -> 81, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. I think you forgot to change the BCs when you did the replacement $\tau\to2\pi L t$ and $x\to2\pi L x$. In particular, the initial condition for the derivative of $P$ gets a factor of $L$, which changes the behaviour dramatically. In particular, I again see no convergence.

Comment: The best I was able to do was to do the following ``n = 7000;
eqtot = Join[eqs, bcs];
sol1 = NDSolveValue[
    eqtot, {P[\[Tau], x], Q[\[Tau], x]}, {\[Tau], 0, 12 \[Pi]}, {x, 0,
      2 \[Pi]}, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "TemporalVariable" -> \[Tau], 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> n, "MaxPoints" -> n}}}]; // Timing''

Comment: @user12588 You are right. Code been updated. Maybe we can play with parameter `A` in `Derivative[1, 0][P][0, x]/(2 Pi L) == A Cos[2 Pi L x]`  to get stable result. Is your current parameter `A=10` related to some physical reason or just to your arbitrary choice?

Comment: Alas, I don't think the plot generated by your latest attempt is very stable. The one I posted previously does a better job, I think. My feeling is that something like Discontinuous Galerkin Method (DGM) would be useful, possibly with some sort of dynamical mesh refinement as the spikes develop. There are a number of packages (for Python or Fortran users) that do this, such as `Clawpack' (https://www.clawpack.org). These are old enough that I was hoping that MMA would have these readily available.

Comment: @user12588 Do you mean that picture for `A=10` should be like picture for `A=8/Pi` shown above?

Comment: I mean that if I take $\tau = 6 \pi$ and I compare with the code that I wrote above, I get rather different results (and I know that the code above is relatively stable). Indeed for $A=10$, I am expecting the development of a lot of spikes, just the spikes that your code generates are not the ones that my generate and my code appears to match the original paper on this topic (see for instance page 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9708038.pdf).